# What is the best way to share cruisecontrol configurations on a Linux server?

Tags: linux, configuration, shared, cruisecontrol

I have a team that will be using CruiseControl for continuous integration, and CC will be running on a Linux server. More than one team member may need to access the CC configuration itself: changing how tests are run, changing notification rules, etc.

What is the best practice for this?

My first thought was to set up a cc-users group, then make a shared directory somewhere (such as /usr/local, I suppose, or a new directory like /projects), where the directory has r/w for the group.

Am I missing any complications with this plan? Obviously, I've never been in charge of such a project before, otherwise I wouldn't ask such a question.

FWIW, my intention is to have all the cc configuration files under mercurial so we can roll back in case of breakage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have version-controlled the whole of cruisecontrol configuration, along with the project specific config files underneath it.This way, the write-access can be controlled per requirement, using your source control tool's access control method (in our case subversion) thus providing tracking as well. Whomsoever needs to make a change can checkout the file config.xml in their own workspace and make their changes and then commit. You may want to consider the same approach.

Comment: This is basically what we ended up doing, too. I made a cc-users group and /projects/cc folder, as described in my post. We put all the configuration into Mercurial. I wrote a little script that watches this repository and restarts cruisecontrol if anything changes.